# WATIN keeps crashing with HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, watin

I keep getting this on IE6 using Windows XP

```
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException : RunScript failed
  ----> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I added my domain to the Trusted Sites but still same issue.

This error didn't happen with Windows 7 64-bit with IE9

Here is where it crashes

```
 browser.Image(Find.ByAlt("Use a password")).Click();
 browser.TextField(Find.ByName("_MYPW")).TypeText(privateCurrentPassword); // CRASHES HERE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had trouble with this before and its because i was using local variables between postbacks to store the references to the elements.

don't do this

```
    var btn Browser.Button("clientid")
    btn.Click(); //assume that this triggers a postback
    var result = btn.Text;
```

do this

```
    Browser.Button("clientid").Click();
    result = Browser.Button("clientid").Text;
```

Comment: Could you please explain your approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Vista or higher, I believe you'll need to be running with elevated permissions to automate IE.  Being a member of the Administrators group is not enough, you need to run Nunit (or whatever you're using) As Administator.

Comment: I am trying to get it to work with Windows XP and IE6. It works without any issue on XP with IE7 or higher. It runs flawlessly on Windows 7.

Comment: You may still have to be an administrator.

Comment: Yes but my users are not administrators. Any workaround? Can i raise the privilege of a thread to Administrator

Comment: Do the tests work for you on XP as an admin?  I don't have a workaround, but at least you'd know what the problem is and could look for a workaround.

Comment: My account is an Admin but my users won't be admins

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for the exception occurred due to accessing an object which didn't exist anymore due to a navigation happening between getting the object and trying to use it. For example:

```
var myElement = otherElement.Element(Find.ByClass("foo"));
ie.Goto("http://www.google.com");
var result = myElement.ClassName; // Exception thrown here
```